# Compiling python .py to .pyc doesn't happen

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, python

I have read that python will compile the source file **.py** by itself to produce **.pyc**, but this doesn't happen in my case. I have the source file inside `/opt/osqa` folder where I always have to use sudo privileges.

How can I compile this source file manually. I am using ArchLinux. Do I need any specific package?

Comment: Can you give an example on how are you compiling. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: try `python -mcompileall`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.pyc` files are created when files are imported. Usually running a script by itself will not create a compiled file. For instance:

```
% cat tmp.py
print 'in tmp.py'
```

When I run the file normally:

```
% python tmp.py 
in tmp.py
```

there is no `.pyc` file created:

```
% ls tmp.py*
tmp.py
```

However, if I `import tmp` from a live Python interpreter:

```
% python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 14 2013, 09:55:56) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tmp
in tmp.py
>>>
```

then the compiled file is created:

```
% ls tmp.py*
tmp.py  tmp.pyc
```

So, it may be normal behaviour depending on how you are running your script.

Comment: I opened python by `sudo python` and then executed `import settings_style.py` the compilation began but I got an error. Well as it conserns me this question is solved...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the .pyc files are not being created because of permission settings in the directory that you have your python sources. See this for more info: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-create-a-pyc-file.htm

Comment: I was thinking of this too. This is why I also mentioned it. I have also read the link you posted but i have no `py` command mentioned in the link. So do i need any speciffic package for this? There is no package `py` in the official repo https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?page=2&sort=&q=py&maintainer=&flagged= and none in AUR repo https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&K=py

Comment: Try copying the python code to your home directory and compile. Just use normal `python yourcode.py` and see if yourcode.pyc gets created.

Comment: I tried and the compilation started but was terminated because the source file was moved and was therefore not finding the other dependant source files. I ll have to find a way t ocompile it in the folder as is. Will try changing the folder rights to 777 and see what happens.